# Entity Framework 4: Inheritance (table per type) - Derived table has a composite PK

Tags: .net, entity-framework, inheritance

Is it possible to have "table per type" inheritance in the Entity Framework 4 if the derived table has a composite primary key?

Here is my table setup:

```
TABLE: ConfigurationKey (Base Entity)
PK: Id

TABLE: ConfigurationKey_Device (Derived Entity)
PK: ConfigurationKeyId (FK to ConfigurationKey.Id)
PK: DeviceId (FK to Device.Id)
```

For what it's worth, ConfigurationKey is going to be abstract and other types are going to derive from ConfigurationKey.

Using the EF designer, I have:

- Added the inheritance rule
- Deleted ConfigurationKeyId from ConfigurationKey_Device
- Deleted the FK linking ConfigurationKey_Device to ConfigurationKey
- Updated the mapping of the  ConfigurationKey_Device.ConfigurationKeyId column to the inherited Id property.

The error I am now getting is:

> Error 3003: Problem in mapping
>   fragments starting at line xxx:All the
>   key properties (ConfigurationKeys.Id)
>   of the EntitySet ConfigurationKeys
>   must be mapped to all the key
>   properties
>   (ConfigurationKey_Device.ConfigurationKeyId,
>   ConfigurationKey_Device.DeviceId) of
>   table ConfigurationKey_Device.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: It is better not to use composite PK with EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message answers to your question itself.
You are actually trying to inherit from an entity with one-column key with an entity with two-column key.
It seems the better solution will be either to have a ComplexType enclosing the common set of properties, or a common interface implementing the necessary functionality.

Comment: Yes, what I was trying to do didn't make sense. What I thought should be a derived entity was actually more like a joining table. Thanks for your feedback.